# Is it self-plagiarism to copy & paste from my own published paper to my grant application?

Tags: funding, plagiarism, self-plagiarism

If I copy & paste sentences from my own published paper to my grant application, will it be considered self-plagiarism? Is it forbidden? The grant application is not published anywhere; this is an internal submission for the  grant agency.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't properly quote, e.g. in the sense of "I'm asking for money to further investigate a problem I already discussed in [1], where we found the following interesting questions: (quote)"?

Comment: I'd agree that citing is better. Even it's fine for this round (which I think it is fine), in future you may share this grant with your teammates or students, who may lift a couple sentences from the grant for their paper's introduction, it'd be nice to be reminded at that time to avoid accidentally plagiarizing.

Comment: Many questions about plagiarism answer themselves by keeping in mind the following (working) definitions: *plagiarism* is presenting **someone else's** contribution as **your own** contribution; *self-plagiarism* is presenting (your own) **previously published** contribution as a **new** contribution. (Of course, what counts as a contribution depends on the discipline and the context; what is considered boiler-plate in one can be a genuine contribution in another.) For a grant proposal: Any text not describing your new contribution for which you apply for support is not covered.

Comment: I think the question identified as a duplicate is a bit broader than the question asked here. I think we need a dedicated question for this specific use case. Thus, I vote to re-open. I'd be happy to offer a bounty.